# Embed XML file into PDF

Tags: java, adobe, livecycle

I need to embed an XML file (or simple text file) into a PDF generated via Java and Adobe LiveCycle SOAP call. 
I can't use iText or another library but only HTML code submitted to LiveCycle for transformation.

How can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the LiveCycle server you can set up a simple process that makes use of the XSLT service bundled in Foundation (available on every LC installation) to transform the HTML to something that your PDF will consume. I can give advice but need more details on your environment and LC modules installed in your server.